# What does '\0' mean?

Tags: c++

I can't understand what the '\0' in the two different place mean in the following code:

```
string x = "hhhdef\n";
cout << x << endl;
x[3]='\0';
cout << x << endl;
cout<<"hhh\0defef\n"<<endl;
```

Result:

> hhhdef
>
> hhhef
>
> hhh

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Where do you find this snippet?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

C++ `std::string`s are "counted" strings - i.e., their length is stored as an integer, and they can contain any character. When you replace the third character with a `\0` nothing special happens - it's printed as if it was any other character (in particular, your console simply ignores it).

In the last line, instead, you are printing a C string, whose end is determined by the first `\0` that is found. In such a case, `cout` goes on printing characters until it finds a `\0`, which, in your case, is after the third `h`.

Answer (score 13):

C++ has two string types:

The built-in C-style null-terminated strings which are really just byte arrays and the C++ standard library `std::string` class which is *not* null terminated.

Printing a null-terminated string prints everything up until the first null character. Printing a `std::string` prints the whole string, regardless of null characters in its middle.

Comment: @LearnedfromMistake True to your user name. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

`\0` is the NULL character, you can find it in your `ASCII table`, it has the value 0.

It is used to determinate the end of C-style strings.

However, C++ class `std::string` stores its size as an integer, and thus does not rely on it.

Answer (score 5):

You're representing strings in two different ways here, which is why the behaviour differs.

The second one is easier to explain; it's a C-style raw char array.  In a C-style string, `'\0'` denotes the *null terminator*; it's used to mark the end of the string.  So any functions that process/display strings will stop as soon as they hit it (which is why your last string is truncated).

The first example is creating a fully-formed C++ `std::string` object.  These don't assign any special meaning to `'\0'` (they don't have null terminators).

Answer (score 4):

The `\0` is treated as `NULL` Character. It is used to mark the end of the string in C.

In C, string is a pointer pointing to array of characters with `\0` at the end. So following will be valid representation of strings in C.

```
char *c =”Hello”;    // it is actually Hello\0
char c[] = {‘Y’,’o’,’\0′};
```

The applications of ‘\0’ lies in determining the end of string .For eg : finding the length of string.

Answer (score 1):

The \0 is basically a null terminator which is used in C to terminate the end of string character , in simple words its value is null in characters basically gives the compiler indication that this is the end of the String Character
Let me give you example -
As we write printf("Hello World"); /* Hello World\0
here we can clearly see \0 is acting as null ,tough printinting the String in comments would give the same output .